# 'No module named 'deploy' : What does this error mean and how do I fix it?

Tags: python, rest, heroku, flask

I created my first Flask app - a very basic API to take data from a local database and return JSON data. The API works on a local port. I then tried to host it on Heroku and that was successful as well - it says Build Succeeded.

However, when I try to run the app, it throws up this Application Error. When I viewed the `heroku logs --tail`, it shows this error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'deploy'`.

[Here](https://flask-restful-arsenal.herokuapp.com/)'s the app.

Here's my code for the API:

```
from flask import Flask, request
from flask_restful import Resource, Api
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from json import dumps
from flask_jsonpify import jsonify

db_connect = create_engine('sqlite:///arsenal.db')

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)


class Players(Resource):

    def get(self):
        player_dict = dict()

        conn = db_connect.connect() # connect to database
        query = conn.execute("SELECT * FROM Players") 

        players = [i for i in query.cursor.fetchall()]
        for player in players:
            player_dict.update({player[1]:player[2]})

        return {'players': player_dict} 

api.add_resource(Players, '/players') # Route_1
if __name__ == '__main__':
     app.run(port='5200')
```

What am I doing wrong? I followed this blog [here](https://medium.com/@ashiqgiga07/deploying-rest-api-based-flask-app-on-heroku-part-2-54698cf7c96d) and [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=skc-ZEU9kO8&t=489s) YouTube video in case that's relevant.

**Edit 1**: The files in the folder are - this code above in `server.py`, `requirements.txt`, `Procfile`, `runtime.txt` and `arsenal.db` - the db I connect to in this code. The repository is [here](https://github.com/AbhishekSharma99/arsenal_rest)

**Edit 2**: I've tried uninstalling and installing Flask as suggested by @Stanley but unfortunately the problem still persists.

**Edit 3**: The `Procfile` contains  `web: gunicorn deploy: app`

Comment: How is the folder setup, can you add that?

Comment: Do you mean what's in the folder? There's this code above in `server.py`, `requirements.txt`, `Procfile`, `runtime.txt` and `arsenal.db` - the db I connect to in this code. I should update the question to include these details as well. @Stanley

Comment: Looking through the code i cant see that you are trying to import deploy or even use an instance of the module, is there more code or am i overlooking something?

Comment: That's exactly what I want to understand as well. I'm not sure what this deploy module is and where it's coming from. There's no more code or files, you can take my word on that.

Comment: I see, thhis may be a little out of my leauge as i am proficient in python, but havent touched flask as much as i would like to! however looking through the internet, it seems like a solution has been to pip uninstall flask and the install it again, have you tried that?

Comment: No offence but what internet did you look through because I had been Googling for twenty minutes straight and drew zip before posting this question. Nevertheless, I shall try that now but I'm not sure if that will help. Thank you for your time

Comment: Questions on Stack Overflow must be self-contained. Please [edit] your question and include the contents of your `Procfile`. I suspect that's where `deploy` is mentioned.

Comment: Also, `pip uninstall` and `pip install` won't solve anything on Heroku. Your dependencies must all be defined in a `requirements.txt` or `Procfile` / `Procfile.lock`—those are the only correct ways to install Python libraries on Heroku.

Comment: Just did @Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The `Procfile` contains `web: gunicorn deploy: app`

The formatting of this file is very important. If there is actually a space before `web:`, remove it.

The arguments passed to `gunicorn` [tell it what module and variable it should us as the WSGI entry point](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/run.html#gunicorn). In your case, you module is `server` (the name of your file) and your WSGI callable is `api`.

Putting that all together, your `Procfile` should contain:

```
web: gunicorn server:api
```

Note that there is no space between `server` and `api`.

Comment: I wrestled a lot with gunicorn but in the end settled for uwsgi. Now my app isn't showing  `Application Failed` but `Internal Server Error`. I guess that's an improvement?

Comment: Application failed and internal server error are probably the same thing: an HTTP 500 response. In either case, check your server logs (e.g. via `heroku logs`). You should find some more useful information there. If you can't solve the problem or find an existing question, feel free to post another one.